# UiAutomator Android does not recognize alert pop

Tags: android, appium, android-uiautomator

[UiAutomator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BeBXC.jpg)
UiAutomator does not recognize this error msg id so I cant validate this error msg in my test automation. I am using java, appium, Testng and real android device

Comment: what you had tried so far?

Comment: Question not clear. Please put, details  or put some screen shot.

Answer (score 0):

The error popup is a different window and error is not one of the properties show.

I think the only option you have is to set the *content description* with something you can identify

```
editText.setContentDescription("error: Printer not found or not supported");
```

then you can look for it.

At the same time, it will help accessibility and screen readers to detect the condition.